# Calculate sum based on different dates

Tags: date, sum

I'm new to Stackoverflow and I need your help for this problem.
I have a table (sql 2014 and use vb.net) like this:

```
ID  Codfisc  Dal         Al
1   xxxxxxx  2017/08/08  2017/08/14
```

I have developed this code:

```
Dim a As Date = Date.Parse(TextBox2.Text)
    Dim b As Date = Date.Parse(TextBox3.Text)
    Dim source2 As String = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim sql2 As String = "select SUM(DATEDIFF(day, dal, al)+1) AS Total FROM Tab1 WHERE codfisc = @codfisc and Dal >=@Dal and Al <=@al"
    Dim conn2 As New SqlConnection(source2)
    conn2.Open()
    Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand(sql2, conn2)
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Codfisc", Me.GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(8).Text)
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dal", a)
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Al", b)
    Dim dr2 As SqlDataReader
    dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader()
    While dr2.Read()

        TextBox4.Text = dr2("Total").ToString()

        If IsDBNull(dr2("Total")) Then
            TextBox4.Text = "0"
        End If


    End While

    conn2.Close()
```

So if I search from `2017/08/08` to `2017/08/14`, the `textbox4.text=7` and is correct! But if I search `2017/08/08` to `2017/08/13` the `textbox4.text=0` instead of `textbox4.text=6`!!

Thank you so much to everyone.